# FileInputStream NullpointerException

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to read a properties file `/res/version.num`. 
But all I get is a NPE.

```
try {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/version.num");
    logger.writeLog(JammEnum.INFO, "version.num path: " + url.getPath());
    File prop_file = new File(url.getPath());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(prop_file);
    prop.load(fis);
    fis.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    logger.writeLog(JammEnum.ERROR, "File not found: version.num");
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    logger.writeLog(JammEnum.ERROR, "Cannot read version.num");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is:

```
(II) - version.num path: /home/andreas/Programmieren/Java/Jamm/bin/res/version.num
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jamm.gui.InfoGui.<init>(InfoGui.java:83)
    at jamm.gui.FinanzmanagerGui$ButtonInfoListener.actionPerformed(FinanzmanagerGui.java:553)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Line 83 is: FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(prop_file);

The path for the file is logged correct. But why do I get this Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example.

```
$ cat src/PrintVersion.java 
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * @author peter.lawrey
 */
public class PrintVersion {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = PrintVersion.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/version.num");
        String version = asString(is);
        System.out.println("Version: "+version);
    }

    public static String asString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        for(int len; (len = is.read(bytes))>0;)
            baos.write(bytes, 0, len);
        return baos.toString();
    }
}
$ cat src/res/version.num 
version 1.0
$ javac src/PrintVersion.java
$ ls src
PrintVersion.class  PrintVersion.java  res
$ java -cp src PrintVersion
Version: version 1.0
```

---

The `url` is null as it couldn't find the resource.  Even if it wasn't null this is not the right way to get a file as it will only work if the file is on the filesystem.

You should try

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
                 .getResourceAsInputStream("/res/version.num");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answere. But I still get this NPE. Is the path correct?  Sorry for all those questions, Im quite new in coding. Currently i have the file in "Project"/src/res/version.num

Comment: The path you give has to be relative to your class path. e.g. if `target/classes/` is in your class path is needs to be in a subdirectory called res. i.e. `target/classes/res/version.num`

Comment: PAH. I cant get it working. My folder structure is [HERE](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/folderstructure.png/) and here is my .classpath and current code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/at7GNUnR)

Comment: I suspect you need to drop the leading '/' from the path.  This has worked for me in Tomcat, but may not work in plain Java. See my example.

Comment: Ok, InputStream works (checked with your asStream Method -> thanks for it). But when I read the properties - prop.read(is) - I´m getting the NPE. Content of version.num is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/AB63bSzK)

Comment: That's because `is` is `null` when it fails to find the file.

Comment: is is not null. I checked it with your asString method. But when I comment out asString and use prop.load(is) instead, I get the NPE

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks,... such a stupid mistake! I was searching for hours :( 1000x Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), not FileInputStream.